# PHP Loads Different MySQL Server Version

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, php

I have installed MySQL 5.6.9 dev on Ubuntu 12.10 32bit, instead of using apt-get to install stable version 5.5.29.

My PHP5, Apache and MySQL are all working, however, I do not see MySQL section using phpinfo.

I thought I had not enabled MySQL in php.ini. I "apt-get install php5-mysql", then I could see the MySQL section under phpinfo, but it shows client api library version 5.5.29 which is not correct since I did not install MySQL 5.5.29.

I think it is something related to php5-mysql. How i can configure PHP to use MySQL 5.6.9, which is the only version MySQL I installed on my machine?

Comment: I think that's just the API version, it does not suggest your MySQL version. Does it connect to your MySQL?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly. just php can not find it.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ do you mean I do not need to care about the api version? if php connects to mysql, it should not be a problem?